How to use eas secret variables when in eas.json, however i dont want to confuse with .env variables that i have locally
I am trying to deploy an app but I am finding difficulties deploying the app using the eas secret vars.
I have successfully stored the variables in eas secret but I do not know how to use them in eas.json and I have seen some answers that you should create a app.config.js but I don't want to confuse the local variable with the secret from eas.
This is the .env file:

EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL=localhost...
EXPO_PUBLIC_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL=localhost

In eas.json I want to update this one:
"production": {
      "channel": "production",
      "env": {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "www.production.com", // I want the secret variable
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL": "www.production2.com" // I want the secret variable
      }
    }


I wrote up a pretty detailed guide. Give it a close read to get a better understanding how env variables in Expo and EAS work. You can find it here:
Solution for Using Environment Variables in Expo with EAS Build
In short, here's your answer to the eas secrets specific question:
If you want to use your local environment variables during EAS builds:

Create the same variables in your Expo project’s secrets. You can find them here:
https://expo.dev/accounts/<username>/settings/secrets

Update your eas.json to tell EAS which secrets to use for specific branches (e.g., development, production):
"development": {
  "autoIncrement": true,
  "developmentClient": true,
  "distribution": "internal",
  "env": {
    "EXPO_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN": "EXPO_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    "EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL": "EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL",
    "EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY": "EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY"
  },
  "channel": "development"
}



This tells EAS to look for EXPO_PUBLIC_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN in the secrets and retrieve its value during the build.
